# Print the first few files in a massive folder on mac (shell)

Tags: macos, shell, ls

I have a folder with 650k files. I wanted to see the names of a few files in the directory so I ran: `ls folder | head` but the command just got stuck. How could I quickly output the names of just a few files in a huge folder on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with simply running `ls folder | head` is that `ls` performs sorting first. Some of the other answers on the internet recommend running `ls -U` to avoid sorting but this does not work on macOS (these answers are usually found on linux forums). However, checking `man ls` on my mac I found:

> -f      Output is not sorted.  This option turns on the -a option.

Just be aware that `ls -f | head` may still take more time than you would expect normally. I am not quite sure why to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ls` which may incur processing on file attributes/sorting, try using file globbing:

```
printf '%s\n' * | head
```